# Cloudflare e Github Pages com erro de DNS

Tags: https, dns, github

Criei uma page estática e publiquei no Github pages, até então com o domínio padrão *username.github.io/repo* tava funcionando tudo de boas, mas então comprei um domínio *.net* na Locaweb, e quando tentei conectar com **Cloudflare** também, não ta funcionando, sempre dá o erro DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

**Configurações Cloudflare:**
[image: Configurações Cloudflare]

**Github:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro apresentado no Chrome:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que pode estar errado?

Tentei seguir alguns vários tutoriais, mas nenhum antecipou esse erro e como resolver

Comment: Seu domínio já está direcionando para o cloudflare, mas o subdomínio "www" não parece corretamente configurado. Ao entrar no endereço natanapps(...) responde com 404. Recomendava configurar o redirecionamento do www para a raiz do domínio diretamente no cloudflare inclusive forçando o uso de https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A propagação de DNS pode demorar até 48h para ocorrer em todo o mundo. Entretanto, geralmente demora poucas horas.

Para verificar a propagação de DNS recomendo utilizar o site https://www.whatsmydns.net/, colocando o seu domínio e a opção `A`, para verificar o IP que está respondendo pelo mesmo. Ou um subdomínio e `A` ou `CNAME`, de acordo com a sua configuração. Também pode fazer o mesmo com outros tipos de configurações, como `MX`, para verificar o servidor de emails.

Comment: Entendi! Lá com subdomínio e ```CNAME``` está tudo marcado em vermelho ainda, só com ```A``` que só falta um...